# Flutter Firebase: Do I need to add firebase implementations to build.gradle?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently using FlutterFire but am a bit confused with the installation [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android).

I have added Firestore and Authentication to my project in `pubspec.yml` and it works. However, I am currently working on implementing [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview) and am unsure how to install. All I did was install it in the `pubspec.yml` just like the other packages but it's not working.

I've been watching tutorials trying to find and answer, and I've found that many of them use this line in their `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {  
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

When I read the documentation, it did not mention this line for `implementation platform(com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')` and I am unsure if I need this or if this is for a previous version of FlutterFire.

Comment: I have the same concern.